# ivy:listmodule does not find an existing module

Tags: ant, ivy

We have our shared Ivy repository on an nginx web server reachable within our intranet.
I configured a `url` resolver to read from the shared repository and an `ssh` resolver to write to it, mostly following Jason Grimes' excellent [blog post on managing dependencies in non-Java projects](http://www.jasongrimes.org/2012/01/using-apache-ivy-to-manage-directory-dependencies-in-non-java-projects).

Now I just successfully published a module to the repository via the `ssh` resolver.
In my SFTP client I can see the directory structure and files sitting in the directory served by the web server:

```
com.organization/modulename/ivy-modulename-2.0.1.xml.md5
com.organization/modulename/ivy-modulename-2.0.1.xml.sha1
com.organization/modulename/ivy-modulename-2.0.1.xml
com.organization/modulename/modulename-2.0.1.zip.md5
com.organization/modulename/modulename-2.0.1.zip.sha1
com.organization/modulename/modulename-2.0.1.zip
```

However, when I execute `ivy:listmodule` it doesn't seem to find it. Frankly, it doesn't output anything apart from the `ivysettings` initialization output.

This is the Ant target I am executing:

```
<!-- ================================
     target: check-already-in-repo

     Check if the current version of a module already exists in the (shared) repository.
     ================================ -->
<target name="check-already-in-repo">
    <ivy:listmodules resolver="shared" organisation="${ivy.organisation}" module="${ivy.module}" revision="${version}" property="already-in-repo" value="true"/>

    <ac:if>
        <isset property="already-in-repo"/>
        <then>
            <echo>${ivy.module} ${version} already exists in the repository.</echo>
            <echo>Skipping publishing of ${ivy.module}.</echo>
        </then>
    </ac:if>
</target>
```

And this is the only output:

```
$ ant check-already-in-repo -Dversion=2.0.1 -Divy.organisation=com.organization -Divy.module=modulename
Buildfile: [...]/build.xml

check-already-in-repo:
[ivy:listmodules] :: Apache Ivy 2.4.0-rc1 - 20140315220245 :: http://ant.apache.org/ivy/ ::
[ivy:listmodules] :: loading settings :: file = [...]/build/ivysettings.xml

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 0 seconds
```

I checked the value of `ivy.shared.default.root` and the corresponding ivy and artifact patterns and they're all matching (I kept them simple).

I tried it with the `glob` matcher and called `ivy:listmodules` with `organization=*`, `module=*` and `revision=*`, so it should in every case return *something*. Which it doesn't.

What do I miss?

Here's the rest of the relevant config:

```
<ivysettings>

    <!-- This file is referenced from multiple projects - DO NOT EDIT! -->

    <!-- shared -->
    <property name="ivy.shared.default.root" value="http://10.79.1.30/ivy"/>
    <property name="ivy.shared.default.ivy.pattern" value="[organisation]/[module]/ivy-[module]-[revision].[ext]"/>
    <property name="ivy.shared.default.artifact.pattern" value="[organisation]/[module]/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]"/>

    <!-- local -->
    <property name="ivy.local.default.root" value="${ivy.default.ivy.user.dir}/local"/>
    <property name="ivy.local.default.ivy.pattern" value="${ivy.shared.default.ivy.pattern}"/>
    <property name="ivy.local.default.artifact.pattern" value="${ivy.shared.default.artifact.pattern}"/>

    <settings defaultResolver="default"/>
    <resolvers>
        <filesystem name="local">
            <ivy pattern="${ivy.local.default.root}/${ivy.local.default.ivy.pattern}" />
            <artifact pattern="${ivy.local.default.root}/${ivy.local.default.artifact.pattern}" />
        </filesystem>
        <!-- read access -->
        <url name="shared">
            <ivy pattern="${ivy.shared.default.root}/${ivy.shared.default.ivy.pattern}" />
            <artifact pattern="${ivy.shared.default.root}/${ivy.shared.default.artifact.pattern}" />
        </url>
        <!-- write access -->
        <ssh name="ssh" host="10.79.1.30" port="22" user="ivy" userPassword="${ivy.ssh.password}" publishPermissions="0664">
            <ivy pattern="${ivy.shared.default.ivy.pattern}" />
            <artifact pattern="${ivy.shared.default.artifact.pattern}" />
        </ssh>
        <chain name="default" returnFirst="true">
            <resolver ref="local"/>
            <resolver ref="shared"/>
        </chain>
    </resolvers>
</ivysettings>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After executing the Ant target with the `-d` (debug) option something caught my eye:

```
$ ant check-already-in-repo -Dversion=2.0.1 -Divy.organisation=com.organization -Divy.module=modulename -d
[...]
[ivy:listmodules]   using shared to list all in http://10.79.1.30/ivy/
[ivy:listmodules] HTTP response status: 403 url=http://10.79.1.30/ivy/
[ivy:listmodules] CLIENT ERROR: Forbidden url=http://10.79.1.30/ivy/
[ivy:listmodules] HTTP response status: 403 url=http://10.79.1.30/ivy/
[ivy:listmodules] CLIENT ERROR: Forbidden url=http://10.79.1.30/ivy/
[ivy:listmodules] problem while listing resources in http://10.79.1.30/ivy/ with shared (java.io.IOException: The HTTP response code for http://10.79.1.30/ivy/ did not indicate a success. See log for more detail.)
[ivy:listmodules] java.io.IOException: The HTTP response code for http://10.79.1.30/ivy/ did not indicate a success. See log for more detail.
[...]
```

It seems for `listmodules` to work, the web server needs to have **directory listings enabled**. And indeed, after adding

```
location /ivy {
    autoindex on;
}
```

to the nginx config and restarting the web server it finally worked as expected!

```
$ ant check-already-in-repo -Dversion=2.0.1 -Divy.organisation=com.organization -Divy.module=modulename
Buildfile: [...]/build.xml

check-already-in-repo:
[ivy:listmodules] :: Apache Ivy 2.4.0-rc1 - 20140315220245 :: http://ant.apache.org/ivy/ ::
[ivy:listmodules] :: loading settings :: file = [...]/build/ivysettings.xml
     [echo] modulename 2.0.1 already exists in the repository.
     [echo] Skipping publishing of modulename.

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 0 seconds
```

Hooray! :-)